# Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I know that there have been posts like this befre but none of the answers seemed to work for me.
I am trying to run the command "mongify check database.yml" when it showes me the error

```
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api)
```

But i do have the activerecord-mysql-adapter inbstalled.
My database.yml file looks like this:

```
sql_connection do
  adapter   "mysql"
  host      "localhost"
  username  "root"
  password  "passw0rd"
  database  "my_database"
end

mongodb_connection do
  host      "localhost"
  database  "my_database"
end
```

If you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do `adapter: mysql2` and not `mysql`
And make sure in your gemfile you have

```
 gem 'mysql2', '0.3.19'
 #Last time I used mysql it was showing some problem with newer versions.
 #Please try checking for newer versions, if they are working.
```

Comment: I tried as you said. now the Error said: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (Could not find 'mysql2' (~> 0.3.10) - did find: [mysql2-0.4.4-x86-mingw32] (LoadError), I also tried changing the gem file to gem 'mysql2', '0.4.4'

Comment: Please run, `gem list | grep mysql2` on  your terminal and tell me which versions of mysql2 shows in it.

Comment: mysql2 (0.4.4 x86-mingw32)

Comment: Can you access mysql from your terminal?

Comment: There is your problem. You got to install mysql in your machine. Are you using ubuntu or mac os?

Comment: I am using windows 10. I'm pretty sure i have mysql installed but I guess something is wtong there :/

Comment: Install mysql in your windows machine, watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=-cHS4HoEFV8) and then try again.

Comment: okay. I have reinstalled mysql and i can acess it now. but the error stays the same.

Comment: did you try opening a new terminal window?  If you just installed it wont be accessible from that stale window. Which ruby version manager are you using?

Comment: I reopened the terminal and as I said, i can access mysql now. But the mongify check database.yml command still shows that error. About the RVM, no idea. I am not even sure what exactly that is. Sorry. this is my first time ever working with Ruby :/